# Search if a number is in a String which is a path

Tags: python, regex

I have a list containing ID numbers  like so:

```
cedulas = [344823, 1234567, 12534, 16537]
```

and i have a list with all the paths of searched images like this:

```
img_path = [
'/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/344823-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg',
 '/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/34482328-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg'  ]
```

this is my code:

```
    for cedula in cedulas:
    for path in im_path:
        if cedula in path:
            print 'Se encontro la imagen {} que corresponde a la cedula {}'.format(path, cedula])
```

the problem is that the code finds the sequence and not the exact number.
for example:

if the `ID == 344823`, with the code above the output is `[True, True]`.

But i want to find the exact match of the number. So the output should be: `[True, False]`

I know that it can be with re but i cant make it happen. Thanks for the help, and im sorry if it a bit confusing.

Comment: Is there a special part in which the number should be placeed

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Qyuv7I/1 Check this regex101 which I wrote!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's your wish. It matches only exact number(s) in `list`. Moreover its complexity is at least, if character length of each number is determined by `len(num)`,  `Ω( len(num) * n^2  )`. I think there should be better design for your purpose.

```
import re


list = [344823, 1234567, 12534, 16537]

list_img = [
'/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/344823-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg',
 '/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/34482328-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg'  ]


for number in list:
    for path in list_img:
        token = str(number)
        if re.search(r'\b' + token + r'\b', path):
            print(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call a `list` list:

```
ids = [344823, 1234567, 12534, 16537]
paths = ['/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/344823-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg', '/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/34482328-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg'  ]

result_set = {}

for id in ids:
    result_set[id] = [len(re.findall('\D%s\D'%str(id), mypath))>0 for mypath in paths]
```

Will give `{344823: [True, False]...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the regex pattern like this:

```
YOUR_NUMBER = 344823
pattern = '\D(YOUR_NUMBER)\D'
```

Comment: How to use it? What would it find? what would it not find?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a regex basing on the ids and search with it:

```
import re
l = [344823, 1234567, 12534, 16537]
img_path = [
 '/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/344823-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg',
 '/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/34482328-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg'  ]
r = "(" + '|'.join(map(lambda x : str(x),list)) + ")-"
# => '(344823|1234567|12534|16537)-'
filter(lambda p: re.search(r, p) , img_path)
# ['/home/diego/Escritorio/LIGD/Secundary/344823-20180730@091239-L13_0_31_626-S.jpg']
```

Regex finds any numbers listed followed by `-`, e.g `(12|16)-`.